# Don't understand why I'm receiving EXC_BAD_ACCESS in xCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I don't understand why I'm getting a EXC BAD ACCESS error when I call the mineHit method in my .m file. I understand that it's indicating that the button array has been released, but I don't understand why It would have been released at all.

```
#import "basicsViewController.h"

@implementation basicsViewController
@synthesize resetGame;
@synthesize scoreLabel;
@synthesize timeLabel;
@synthesize time;
@synthesize score;

-(void)newGame{
int index=0;
int yAxis=70;
for(int y=0;y<100;y=y+10){
    int xAxis=20;
    for( int x = 1; x < 11; x++) {
        buttonArray[index] = [[UIButton alloc]init];
        buttonArray[index] = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [buttonArray[index] setTag:index];
        [buttonArray[index] addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        buttonArray[index].frame = CGRectMake(xAxis, yAxis, 26.0, 26.0);
        NSLog(@"tag:%d xAxis:%d yAxis:%d",buttonArray[index].tag,(int)buttonArray[index].frame.origin.x,(int)buttonArray[index].frame.origin.y);
        [self.view addSubview:buttonArray[index]];
        xAxis=xAxis+28;
        index=x+y;
    }
    yAxis=yAxis+28;
}

//generate bombs

for (int bombs=0;bombs<10;bombs++){

    bombArray[bombs]= (arc4random()%99);
    //TODO compare against bombArray to make sure of no duplicates
    NSLog(@"BOMB AT %d",bombArray[bombs]);

}

}



- (IBAction)resetPress:(id)sender {
[self newGame];
}


- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)button
{
BOOL hit;
NSLog(@"SELECTED BUTTON:%d",button.tag);
for (int b=0;b<10;b++){
    if (button.tag==bombArray[b]){
        //BOMB HIT
        hit=YES;
        b=10;
    }
    else {
        //no bomb
        hit=NO;
    }
}
if (hit==YES){
    //if hit
    NSLog(@"HIT AT %d",button.tag);
    [self mineHit];

}
else {
    //if not hit
    NSLog(@"%d is clean",button.tag);
    [self cleanHit:button];

}
}

-(void)mineHit{

for (int d=0;d<100;d++){
    NSLog(@"%i",buttonArray[d].tag);
    buttonArray[d].enabled=NO;
    [buttonArray[d] setTitle:@"*" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
}

}
-(void)cleanHit:(UIButton*)button{
button.enabled=NO;
[button setTitle:@"!" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self newGame];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[self setResetGame:nil];
[self setScoreLabel:nil];
[self setTimeLabel:nil];
[super viewDidUnload];

}
@end
```

Here is my .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
NSInteger bombArray[];
UIButton *buttonArray[];
@interface basicsViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *resetGame;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *scoreLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timeLabel;
@property int time;
@property int score;
-(void)newGame;
-(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)button;
-(void)mineHit;
-(void)cleanHit:(UIButton*)button;

@end
```

Comment: The way you set up and initialize the buttons in "`buttonArray`" looks really suspicious to me.

Comment: how so? I've used this method before, because I wanted to make an array of buttons and still be able to access button properties.

Comment: Why aren't you using NSArray?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to use UIButton specific properties when the button is stored in a NSArray.

Comment: Just cast a NSObject the you get to UIButton, like this: (UIButton*)[array objecyAtIndex:i];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I compile your code I get four warnings.  All four warnings are the same and say:

> Tentative array definition assumed to have one element

The warnings apply to the definition of your `bombArray` and `buttonArray` arrays in the interface (.h) file.

If we give the two arrays a size your `-mineHit` method works fine.

Change the beginning of your .h file to:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
NSInteger bombArray[10];
UIButton *buttonArray[100];
@interface basicsViewController : UIViewController
```

The compiler generates warnings for  a reason and it is a good idea to try and get your code to compile cleanly with no warnings or errors.

**Update:**  While we are here there is no reason why you couldn't move these arrays inside the interface and declare them as instance variables.  Doing this would mean that the arrays are associated with an individual instance of the view controller. It is unlikely that you'd have multiple instances of this view controller but it is better to do it correctly now than get bitten later.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface basicsViewController : UIViewController {
    NSInteger bombArray[10];
    UIButton *buttonArray[100];
}
```

Interestingly, moving the declaration into the interface turns the warnings into errors.

Comment: I originally didn't want to establish array limits because I wanted to be able to expand the game, so also expand the array

Comment: Yeah, but if you don't specify the array size then it assumes a single element and it doesn't allocate enough memory for the array.  I'm surprised the code ran as far as it did.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a suggestion to move the declaration of the arrays inside the interface definition.